# jq: How to convert flat json into nested one

Tags: json, nested, jq

I've been trying to re-arrange a pretty flat json into structure with more depth, so far without any success. Here's my source data:

`[  {
    "id": "27",
    "time": "2017-12-21 07:24:00",
    "service_name": "prices",
    "version": "61f4u8e",
    "event": "Success"
  },
  {
    "id": "28",
    "time": "2017-12-21 07:23:00",
    "service_name": "prices",
    "version": "21c2f7d",
    "event": "Fail"
  },
  {
    "id": "29",
    "time": "2017-12-21 07:21:00",
    "service_name": "cart",
    "version": "9ff24c4",
    "event": "Success"
  }
]`

The result should look like this:

`[
  {
    "name": "cart",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:21:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Success",
          "version": "9ff24c4"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "prices",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:24:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Success",
          "version": "61f4u8e"
        }
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:23:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Fail",
          "version": "21c2f7d"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]`

So, basically grouping by service_name and moving the other fields around a little.

So far I've managed to group, but only one level:

`group_by(.service_name) | map({name: .[0].service_name, data: .})`
How can I shuffle around the other values, assuming the input will always have all fields as in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`jq`** solution:

```
jq '[group_by(.service_name)[] 
    | .[0].service_name as $name 
    | { name: $name, 
        data: map({ date: .time, 
                    details: {event, version}}) 
      }]' jsonfile
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cart",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:21:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Success",
          "version": "9ff24c4"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "prices",
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:24:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Success",
          "version": "61f4u8e"
        }
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-12-21 07:23:00",
        "details": {
          "event": "Fail",
          "version": "21c2f7d"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RomamPerekhrest.